# Express importing app from server.js is giving me an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, commonjs

I have created an express server in my `server.js` file, and I export `app` from it.

```
//server.js    

require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

const connectToDb = require("./connectToDb")




connectToDb().catch(console.dir)


app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("unable to find");
});

module.exports = app
```

I import `app` from `server.js` in the `connectToDb.js` file

```
//connectToDb.js


const app = require("./server")
const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const connectToDb = async () =>{
  try {
    await client.connect();

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    console.log("hello")
  }
}


module.exports = connectToDb
```

It connects succesfully to the database, but when it reaches `app.listen` it gives me this error: `TypeError: app.listen is not a function`. I don't know why it gives me an error because I have exported `app`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have a cyclic dependency. The two files import each other, *and* inside `server.js` you make a call immediately on load. In the moment you call `connectToDb` inside of `server.js`, the `server.js` file has not fully executed yet and hence the module export has not yet happened. Either way it's something you should try to avoid (cyclic dependencies).

Just resolve the cycle by passing the `app` to the `connectToDb` function as a parameter instead of importing it:

```js
//server.js    

require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const connectToDb = require("./connectToDb")
connectToDb(app).catch(console.dir)

app.use((req, res) => {
  res.status(404).send("unable to find");
});

module.exports = app


// connectToDb.js

const MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true
});
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const connectToDb = async (app) =>{
  try {
    await client.connect();

    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    app.listen(port, () => {
        console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  } finally {
    await client.close();
    console.log("hello")
  }
}


module.exports = connectToDb
```

Comment: Okay, thank you for your solution! Do you think that this is a good way to connect to the database?

Comment: I think it's reasonable. Personally I prefer to have a "main line" of execution, rather than passing control around too much. So I would have used a callback from the connectToDb method to pass control back to the app, rather than passing the app object around. But I can't really demonstrate why that is better. Just a little easier to read perhaps.

Comment: Could you demonstrate the example in code? @ChristianFritz